# How to download AES 128 encrypted HLS Stream?

Tags: 20.04, video, encryption, wget, video-streaming

I want to download AES 128 encrypted HLS stream into a mp4 on Ubuntu 20.04.

I have the m3u8 file but it has URI for key as `k/timestamp`.

I have the timestamp file but it shows bizarre text when opened using text editor.

Comment: If you're trying to obtain DRM'd content, then you might want to [learn how the m3u format works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) and how it accomplishes its objectives. From there, you will be able to reverse-engineer something to get the data that you need.

Comment: Well, I have read that and I didn't get anything helpful from there.